# What is the use of FileBeat while parsing logs in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am not understanding the concept why file beat is required while we have a logstash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With filebeat you are able to collect and forward logfiles from one or many remote servers.
There is also a option to add source specific fields to your log entries.

You have several output options like elasticsearch or logstash for further analysis/filtering/modification.

Just imagine 20 or 200 machines running services like databases, webservers, hosting applications and containers. And now you need to collect all the logs...

only with logstash you'll be pretty limited in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Beats are light-weight agents used primarily for forwarding events from multiple sources. Beats have a small footprint and use fewer system resources than Logstash.

Logstash has a larger footprint, but provides a broad array of input, filter, and output plugins for collecting, enriching, and transforming data from a variety of sources.

Please note though that filebeat is also capable of parsing for most use cases using Ingest Node as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-ingest-node.html).